# SQL set operation with different number of columns in each set

Tags: sql-server, set

Let say I have set 1:

```
1   30  60
2   45  90
3   120 240
4   30  60
5   20  40
```

and set 2

```
30  60
20  40
```

I would like to do some sort of union where I only keep rows 1,4,5 from set 1 because the latter 2 columns of set 1 can be found in set 2.

My problem is that set based operations insist on the same numnber of **columns**.

I've thought of concatenating the columns contents, but it feels dirty to me.

Is there a 'proper' way to accomplish this?

**I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2**

In the end, I would like to end up with

```
1   30  60
4   30  60
5   20  40
```

**CLEARLY I need to go sleep as a simple join on 2 columns worked.... Thanks!**

Comment: as you need only matching column you need to do join as GBN has described... why you want to do in union???

Comment: UNION is the opposite of what you want: this is an INTERSECTION, but probably easiest to do it using EXISTS...

Comment: @Richard Inglis: FYI, See my update for JOIN types please

Comment: @Matt: if you're tired... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally asking for

> give me the rows in t1 where the 2 columns match in T2

So if the output is only rows 1, 4 and 5 from table 1 then it *is* a set based operation and can be done with EXISTS or INTERSECT or JOIN. For the "same number of column", then you simply set 2 conditions with an AND. This is evaluated per row

EXISTS is the most portable and compatible way and allows any column from table1

```
select  id, val1, val2
from    table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.val1 = t2.val1 AND t1.val2 = t2.val2)
```

INTERSECT requires the same columns in each clause and not all engines support this (SQL Server does since 2005+)

```
select  val1, val2
from    table1
INTERSECT
select  val1, val2
from    table2
```

With an INNER JOIN, if you have duplicate values for `val1, val2` in table2 then you'll get more rows than expected. The internals of this usually makes it slower then EXISTS

```
select  t1.id, t1.val1, t1.val2
from    table1 t1
        JOIN
        table2 t2 ON t1.val1 = t2.val1 AND t1.val2 = t2.val2
```

Some RBDMS support IN on multiple columns: this isn't portable and SQL Server doesn't support it

Edit: some background

Relationally, it's a semi-join ([One](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_semi_join_in_SQL), [Two](http://www.dbspecialists.com/files/presentations/semijoins.html)).

SQL Server does it as a ["left semi join"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191218.aspx)

INTERSECT and EXISTS in SQL Server usually give the same execution plan. The join type is a "left semi join" whereas INNER JOIN is a full "equi-join".

Comment: None of these answers match the OP's suggested output either

Comment: @Andomar: The INTERSECT doesn't because we can't include theh id column but both EXISTS and JOIN do. How can you say that? I thought you knew SQL... so explain what is wrong or remove your downvote

Comment: I'd written test data for my answer, which I used on your queries, and the results don't match.  He's basically repeating rows from table with less rows, which I guess you could do in SQL if you had a spare half hour :)  Not my downvote btw.

Comment: @Andomar: can you add your test script please? (saves me 10 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `union` which, as opposed to `union all`, eliminates duplicates:

```
select  val1, val2
from    table1
union
select  val1, val2
from    table1
```

EDIT: Based on your edited question, you can exclude rows that match the second table using a `not exists` subquery:

```
select  id, col1, col2
from    table1 t1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    table2 t2
        where   t1.col1 = t2.col1
                and t1.col2 = t2.col2
        )
union all
select  null, col1, col2
from    table2
```

If you'd like to exclude rows from `table2`, omit `union all` and everything below it.

Comment: Right, but then I won't have the 1st column of the 1st set, which is what I'm after.

Comment: Both of these are wrong and give incorrect results. It has UNION like OP asked for but UNION isn't needed. The question update shows this.